# How do I display Android Monitor/LogCat in Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting one of those "Unfortunately (your app) has stopped" errors before it even gets to my first *OnCreate()*, and, trying to be a good Stack Overflow netizen, I went first to [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

...where it says...

> Note: This answer is using Android Studio 2.2.2
>
> Note 2: I am considering that your device is successfully connected.
>
> The first thing you do when your application crashes is look into the
>   LogCat, at the bottom of Android Studio there's a toolbar with a list
>   of menus:

[image]

> Click on the "Android Monitor" (The one I underlined in the image
>   above. ^)

But I don't **have** that toolbar, even though I'm running Android Studio 2.2.2.
I looked in the Tools, View and Window dropdowns and don't see anything called Android Monitor or Logcat.

So how do I get the tabs and windows referenced in that Stack Overflow link to appear?

***EDIT:***

CommonsWare's comment, below, indicated where Android Monitor was so I can get on with the debugging, but I still don't know where that toolbar came from so they suggested I post a screenshot.  So here it is...

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot of your Android Studio, and we'll see if we can help you find it.

Comment: You might also post a screenshot of the View >Tool Windows fly-out menu, as Android Monitor appears there. It is also accessible via Alt-6.

Comment: _You might also post a screenshot of the View >Tool Windows fly-out menu, as Android Monitor appears there_   Thanks: That's partially the answer to my question, because Android Monitor is there.   So now I can proceed with my debugging, but I'm still curious where that toolbar with the Run, TODO, Android Monitor, Statistic,.. thing comes from.

Comment: ...OK, I've added the screenshot.   You can see that, thanks to CommonWare I've got Android Monitor, so my remaining puzzlement is that toolbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if View > Tool Buttons is checked. If not, check it.

Comment: Bingo!  That was it.

Answer (score 1):

View -> check "Tool Buttons". It looks like you currently have it unchecked. For me this option toggles the menu you are missing.